# How do login to pgadmin with rolename instead of email?

Tags: pgadmin

In pgadmin I have created a new user with a username
`CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password' SUPERUSER;`

But i can't seem to login with it. The pgadmin login screen says "email address" instead of rolename. How do i login now? Where can I find the email address?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the login screen of pgAdmin web mode. It is different from PostgreSQL server login. You must have setup email and password when you setup pgAdmin web for the first time. BTW if you have access to the pgadmin4.db file and dont remember the email/password, then you can remove the file from /.pgadmin/pgadmin4.db and start pgAdmin again.

It also looks like you're using a very old version.